# Why do I get 'variable not in scope' for Just ord <*> Nothing?

Tags: haskell

I'm learning Haskell from a popular [book](http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters).

It includes the [following ghci command](http://learnyouahaskell.com/a-fistful-of-monads#getting-our-feet-wet-with-maybe):

```
ghci> Just ord <*> Nothing  
Nothing
```

When I run this in ghci I get:

```
<interactive>:1:6: error:
    • Variable not in scope: ord :: a0 -> b
    • Perhaps you meant one of these:
        ‘or’ (imported from Prelude), ‘odd’ (imported from Prelude)
```

I think there is a typo, either due to an author mistake or the version of Haskell changing the syntax.

My question is: **Why do I get `variable not in scope` for `Just ord <*> Nothing`?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[A quick search for "ord" on Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=ord) reveals that [it lives in the `Data.Char` module](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Data-Char.html#v:ord). (I have no idea whether it was always there, or whether it only recently got moved there.) So you just need to import `Data.Char` into your `ghci` session.

```
ghci> import Data.Char
ghci> Just ord <*> Nothing
Nothing
```

Comment: It's always been there. See the [Haskell 98 `Prelude`](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/standard-prelude.html), which does not have that function. The `Prelude` alternative is `fromEnum`.

Comment: Thanks @dfeuer - I tried that and it needed type hints - have you tried to make that one work?

Comment: @hawkeye, you can use `Just (fromEnum :: Char -> Int) <*> Nothing`.